# Using a for loop to print out students and their grades from highest to lowest , using an object

Tags: java, object, this, selection-sort

So in this program I am asking the size of a class of students, taking in each student and the grade associated with them. myStudents[i] then holds each students name and their grade. The problem I am having now is with both of my selectionSort. I was supposed to arrange each students by grades (from highest to lowest. Which I think I did correctly in public static void selectionSort(student[] myStudents), but I am not sure how I a supposed to print that out using a for loop when I call selectionSort. Any advice to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Final4{

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the class: ");  
        int num = myInput.nextInt();


        int array[] = new int[num];
        double score;
        student[] myStudents = new student[num];


        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a student name: ");
            myInput.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            String s;
            s = myInput.next();

            System.out.print("Please enter " + s +"'s score: "); 

            score = myInput.nextDouble();

            myStudents[i] = new student(s, score);

        }

    }
    selectionSort()


    public static void selectionSort(student[] myStudents) {


        for (int i = myStudents.length-1; i>0; i--){

            int maxIndex = 0;
            student max = myStudents[0];

            for (int j=1; j<=i; j++)

                if (myStudents[j].getScore() > (max.getScore())) {
                    maxIndex = i;
                }

            student temp = myStudents[i];

            myStudents[i] = myStudents[maxIndex];

            myStudents[maxIndex] = temp;


        }

    }
}
class student {
    String name;
    double score;

    student(String name, double score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I tend to get a little confused once I start incorporating gets and objects. Again, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean print out a for-loop like `Stream.of(strings).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: There's no point in making get methods if you aren't going to make name and score private. You can access them with just student.score and student.name . Also, make sure you take names into account. If the grades are equal you should probably sort by name alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

so your problem was how to print your array of `Student` which is sorted by Selection Sort, right?

On your main method, after looping condition (on creating Student array) add this code.

```
selectionSort(myStudents);

for(Student s: myStudents) {
    System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getScore());
}
```

That code will print your array of students.